# Odds of getting a perfect bracket with constraints

Tags: probability

In our History class we are creating brackets for March Madness, and it got me thinking:
What is the probability of getting a perfect bracket? So, upon some research, I've found the general consensus is about 9.2 quintillion.

But, this is just if you pick a bracket randomly. Never before has a 16 seed beaten a one-seed. What would the probability of picking a random bracket be if you adjusted accordingly, never having a 16-seed beat a one-seed, and how would you calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you get $1$ in $9.2$ quintillion?  I take that to be $1$ in $2^{63}$ as there are $63$ games (after the play-in games).  So now you have only $59$ games to predict.